# Cache Django FileField url Lookups

Tags: django, cloudfiles

I am using django-storage's Mosso backend to store image files in the Rackspace CDN. However, I am facing very slow page loads due to the back and fourth of model.image_field.url lookups to the api. Does anyone know a good way to cache this value?

Comment: Are you using a caching mechanism now?  Post your settings file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using memcached. I just want to not send a request to the cloudfiles api every time I use .url in a template.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got `memcached` up and running on your side, I suggest the `memorised` module:

http://github.com/1stvamp/memorised/

... which is a variant of the [classic Python memoize decorator](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/) -- the `memorized` module eschews local dict caches in favor of Memcache storage. Any “memorised” functions you define are almost as fast as memoized functions* – plus, those Memcache-backed function-call cache persists across all invocations of the Python interpreter process.

I don't know thing one about the RackSpace CDN, but using `memorised` makes my stuff measurably faster, in like a granular and magic-free way.

`*`: in my little bitty statistically-insignificant testing